# How to write a log file with winston on NodeJS

Tags: node.js, logging, winston

I'm building on my NodeJS API a custom logger using Winston.
I'm trying to log into a file but is it not working and cannot understand the issue.
I used some online resources to find out the solution but anything worked.
I used the `transports.File()` and added to my push but nothing happens.

My goal is to add the same logs I'm getting using the logger with the console into the file.
Same format and way of it.

My code

```
/* eslint-disable object-curly-newline */
/* eslint-disable arrow-parens */
/* eslint-disable comma-dangle */
// Logger
// This logger is used to show error/info messages about the status of the API
import winston from 'winston';
import moment from 'moment';
// import logSymbols from 'log-symbols';
import fs from 'fs-extra';
import { logger, NODE_ENV } from '../config';

const transports = [];
const dir = './logs';

// Creating the logs dir if does not exist
if (!fs.existsSync(dir)) {
  fs.mkdirSync(dir);
}

// For development in prod need to check for dev env
// in dev we want more info error tracking
// in prod essential info error message
if (NODE_ENV.env !== 'development') {
  transports.push(
    new winston.transports.Console({
      format: winston.format.combine(
        winston.format.cli(),
        winston.format.splat()
      ),
    }),
    new winston.transports.File({
      level: 'error',
      filename: `${dir}/logs.log`,
    })
  );
} else {
  transports.push(new winston.transports.Console());
}

// Parse meta keys
const parser = string => {
  if (!string) {
    return '';
  }
  if (typeof string === 'string') {
    return string;
  }
  return Object.keys(string).length ? JSON.stringify(string, undefined, 2) : '';
};

// Logger instance
const LoggerInstance = winston.createLogger({
  level: logger.level,
  levels: winston.config.npm.levels,
  format: winston.format.combine(
    winston.format.colorize(),
    winston.format.timestamp(),
    winston.format.errors({ stack: true }),
    winston.format.splat(),
    winston.format.printf(info => {
      const { timestamp, level, message, meta } = info;
      const ts = moment(timestamp)
        .local()
        .format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:ss');
      const metaMsg = meta ? `: ${parser(meta)}` : '';
      // const symbol = level === 'error' ? logSymbols.error : logSymbols.success;
      return `${ts} [${level}] ${parser(message)} ${metaMsg}`;
    })
  ),
  transports,
});

export default LoggerInstance;
```

Comment: Which logs message does not appear in your log file? You set log level to "error" only explicitly. May be you try to log info level messages? NODE_ENV.env what is in your env. configuration?

Comment: So I cannot write the logs file and I'm using the debug level. 
I cannot have in the file my logs at all

Answer (score 0):

While you set log level explicitly to 'error' in your winston transporter, you can not see any messages in debug level in the file. Please change your configuration so that your file. transporter accepts debug level messages too.

```js
    new winston.transports.File({
      level: 'debug',
      filename: `${dir}/logs.log`,
    })
```

Comment: Unfortunate is not working I tried that already via ENV and just writing the level:'' but no file is created ate all